# Como comparar duas listas de nomes em python?

Tags: python, string, lista, comparação

Olá, tudo bem?

Então, tenho duas listas de nome em pdf e gostaria de obter os nomes das pessoas que estão em ambas as listas. Como faria isso em python? Seria melhor em outra linguagem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lista_a = ['ana', 'Bob', 'Mario']
lista_b = ['ana', 'Carlos', 'Pedro']
for nome in lista_a:
    if nome in lista_b:
        print(i)
```

No python quando você coloca o *in* ele verifica se está dentro de algo. Nesse caso dentro da lista_b

Você pode armazenar esse nomes dentro de uma outra lista dando um append ou até mesmo fazer isso com List Comprehensions.

Comment: Olá, Rodrigo. Obrigado pela sua resposta detalhada. Eu deveria ter colocado na pergunta também, mas você saberia qual biblioteca lê pdf? ou se deveria mudar o formato do documento e qual seria o melhor formato?

Comment: Eu nunca trabalhei com PDF no python mas eu já li um artigo sobre PyPDF2  no Realpython
https://realpython.com/pdf-python/  o artigo está em Inglês mas é bem simples de entender

Comment: Obrigado novamente, Rodrigo.